# Shortest Repeating Sub-String

Tags: python, regex, string-matching

I am looking for an efficient way to extract the shortest repeating substring.
For example:

```
input1 = 'dabcdbcdbcdd'
ouput1 = 'bcd'

input2 = 'cbabababac'
output2 = 'ba'
```

I would appreciate any answer or information related to the problem.

Also, in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883688/smallest-repeating-substring), people suggest that we can use the regular expression like

```
re=^(.*?)\1+$
```

to find the smallest repeating pattern in the string. But such expression does not work in Python and always return me a non-match (I am new to Python and perhaps I miss something?).

--- follow up ---

Here the criterion is to look for shortest non-overlap pattern whose length is greater than one and has the longest overall length.

Comment: "Shortest" how? Repeats least times? what about "abcabc ababab"?  "abbba"? "dd" in your first string? Partial matching makes this definition a little odd...

Comment: Exactly. In the first string, `d` should be the correct answer.

Comment: yes, I have added the criterion there. And I think both answers below can already lead me to the final solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A quick fix for this pattern could be

```
(.+?)\1+
```

Your regex failed because it anchored the repeating string to the start and end of the line, only allowing strings like `abcabcabc` but not `xabcabcabcx`. Also, the minimum length of the repeated string should be 1, not 0 (or any string would match), therefore `.+?` instead of `.*?`.

In Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r"(.+?)\1+")
>>> r.findall("cbabababac")
['ba']
>>> r.findall("dabcdbcdbcdd")
['bcd']
```

But be aware that this regex will only find non-overlapping repeating matches, so in the last example, the solution `d` will not be found although that is the shortest repeating string. Or see this example: here it can't find `abcd` because the `abc` part of the first `abcd` has been used up in the first match):

```
>>> r.findall("abcabcdabcd")
['abc']
```

Also, it may return several matches, so you'd need to find the shortest one in a second step:

```
>>> r.findall("abcdabcdabcabc")
['abcd', 'abc']
```

**Better solution:**

To allow the engine to also find overlapping matches, use

```
(.+?)(?=\1)
```

This will find some strings twice or more, if they are repeated enough times, but it will certainly find all possible repeating substrings:

```
>>> r = re.compile(r"(.+?)(?=\1)")
>>> r.findall("dabcdbcdbcdd")
['bcd', 'bcd', 'd']
```

Therefore, you should sort the results by length and return the shortest one:

```
>>> min(r.findall("dabcdbcdbcdd") or [""], key=len)
'd'
```

The `or [""]` (thanks to J. F. Sebastian!) ensures that no `ValueError` is triggered if there's no match at all.

Answer (score 3):

`^` matches at the start of a string. In your example the repeating substrings don't start at the beginning. Similar for `$`. Without `^` and `$` the pattern `.*?` always matches empty string. [Demo](http://ideone.com/vSqaY):

```
import re

def srp(s):
    return re.search(r'(.+?)\1+', s).group(1)

print srp('dabcdbcdbcdd') # -> bcd
print srp('cbabababac')   # -> ba
```

Though It doesn't find the shortest substring.