# How to find a repeating pattern in a list of strings?

Tags: c#, pattern-matching, design-patterns

I have a list of methods from a trace that is taken of a process. I want to detect if anything is essentially called in a loop. For example, I might have

```
method1
    method2
    method2
    method2
```

Might display 'method2 called by method1 3 times in a possible loop'.

```
method3
    method1
    methodd
    methoda
    methodb
    methodc
    methodd
    methoda
    methodb
    methodc
    methodd
```

Would display 'methoda, methodb, methodc, methodd 2 times in a possible loop'.

Obviously, there is no guarantee that there is a loop, but at least we know that there is a repeating pattern. The only input is the list of the children (for example from above method2, method2, method2).

Comment: Do subsequences count? e.g. a,k,b,c,a,g,b,d,a,h,b,e => a,b repeated?

Comment: If not, build a suffix array along with longest common prefixes and find K consecutive LCPs with values > threshold (where K is another threshold)?

Comment: No, subsequences do not count. Only unique repeated patterns.

Comment: Then what I said should work. This is essentially longest repeating substring http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_repeated_substring_problem

Comment: Still does not work as methodA, method1, method2, method3, methodB, method1, method2, method3 would be detected as a loop of method1, method2, method3, which it is not because methodB is called between them.

Comment: Search the LCP values while requiring that the LCPs are consecutive in the source string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a suffix array along with longest common prefixes and find K consecutive LCPs with values > threshold (where K is another threshold)

In the search, require that the found suffixes' candidate LCPs are consecutive in the source string/do not overlap.
Search algorithm:

```
let minimum_iterations = 1
let minimum_pattern_length = 2
let src = source string
let suffix = sorted suffix array, 
             where each entry is suffix i0 (inclusive) to |src| (exclusive)
let lcp = longest common prefixes, 
             where lcp(i) = longest common prefix of suffix(i) and suffix(i-1) when i > 0,
             or 0 if i = 0

for i = 0 to |suffix|:
    if lcp[i] < minimum_pattern_length: continue        
    let j = i
    let iterations = 0
    let last_matched_i0 = suffix[i-1].i0
    while j < |suffix| and lcp[j] >= lcp[i]:
        if (suffix[j].i0 + lcp[i] + 1) = last_matched_i0: 
            iterations++
            last_matched_i0 = suffix[j].i0
        j++

    print 'pattern = ' .. suffix[i][0..lcp[i]] .. ' iterations = ' .. iterations
    print 'starting at ' .. suffix[j-1].i0 .. ' to ' .. suffix[i-1].i0 + lcp[i]

    skip pattern if wanted
```

`(suffix[j].i0 + lcp[i] + 1) = last_matched_i0`
Make sure that the matched pattern is consecutive.
We assume `suffix[j]` includes `suffix[j-1]` if they're both patterns, because in a sorted suffix array `ab` will always come before `abab`

Example:
3ababab65

Suffixes

- 3ababab65
- ababab65
- babab65
- abab65
- bab65
- ab65
- b65
- 65
- 5

Sorted Suffixes along with Longest Common Prefix (LCP - Suffix):
LCP(i) is the longest common prefix between SUFFIX(i) and SUFFIX(i-1)

- 0 - 5
- 0 - 65
- 0 - 3ababab65
- 0 - ab65
- 2 - **ab**ab65
- 4 - **abab**ab65
- 0 - b65
- 1 - **b**ab65
- 3 - **bab**ab65

LCP Candidates:

- **ab**65, **ab**ab65, **ab**abab65 - consecutive, no overlap
- **abab**65, **abab**ab65 - overlap
- **b**65, **b**ab65 - not consecutive
- **bab**65, **bab**ab65 - overlap

Possible patterns:

- ab

You have to modify the code a bit to handle the following case:

ababa

You will have suffixes of aba, and ababa, with LCP of 3

---

Or you could just do this... [Shortest Repeating Sub-String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633996/shortest-repeating-sub-string) ... Donno how efficient it is... but way easier.

Comment: Looks interesting; however, I don't get it. Can you elaborate a bit more, please?

Comment: Thanks alot. Added some bold formatting where I felt it would make the patterns clearer. (Also tried to get rid of the scroll bars, as it makes reading easier)

Answer (score 1):

You could insert the list of children into a linked list as per the order, then run a linked list loop detection algorithm.

e.g. have 2 pointers, 1 pointer that moves a node at a time and another pointer that moves 2 nodes at a time, if a loop exists, the faster pointer will eventually be at the same node as the slower one